webhook route handler working unexpectedly in next.js
I have a simple webhook route handler in Next.js 14.X deployed on the free hobby plan at Vercel.com. I've simplified and refactored the code for better readability. Each webhook request contains images associated with 4 URL. The process fetches these images, converts them into buffers, adds watermarks, and then saves both the original and the watermarked images to Supabase. However, I am encountering an issue where not all images are saved to Supabase. For example, if the webhook is called 10 times, that should result in saving 40 images (10 calls * 4 images each). Yet, it only saves around 20, 24, or sometimes even 28 images, and I cannot identify the problem since I am not receiving any errors.
export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";
export const maxDuration = 60;

const CONCURRENCY_LIMIT = 100;
const RETRY_LIMIT = 3;
const RETRY_BACKOFF = 300; // in ms
const REQUEST_TIMEOUT = 60000; // in ms, increased to 10 seconds

const limit = pLimit(CONCURRENCY_LIMIT);

export async function POST(request) {
  const body = await request.text();
  const { output: images } = await JSON.parse(body);
  // output[] || images[] = Contains public URL of four images.
  try {
    if (!images) {
      throw new TypeError(`Expected 'images' to be defined but got ${images}`);
    }
    await handleImages(images);
  } catch (error) {
    await sendErrorEmail({
      rawBody: body,
    });
  }

  return NextResponse.json({ success: true }, { status: 200 });
}

async function handleImages(images) {
  try {
    const logoBuffer = await fetchLogoBuffer();
    let processedImages = [];

    const promises = images.map((imageURL) =>
      limit(() => processImageDual(imageURL, logoBuffer))
    );

    processedImages = await Promise.allSettled(promises);

    const successfulImages = processedImages
      .filter((result) => result.status === "fulfilled")
      .map((result) => result.value);

    if (successfulImages.length > 0) {
      await updateUserPreviews(successfulImages.map((img) => img.watermarked));
      await updateResultsColumn(successfulImages.map((img) => img.original));
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error in handleImages", error);
    Sentry.captureException(error);
    throw error;
  }
}

async function fetchLogoBuffer() {
  // fetch the logo of my company and return buffer.
  const logoResponse = await fetchWithRetry(
    `${process.env.URL}/logo/watermark.png`
  );
  return await logoResponse.arrayBuffer();
}

async function processImageDual(imageURL, logoBuffer, supabase, training_id) {
  try {
    const imageResponse = await fetchWithRetry(imageURL);
    const buffer = await imageResponse.arrayBuffer();
    const originalUpload = await uploadToSupabase(buffer, "results");
    const watermarkedImage = await applyWatermark(buffer, logoBuffer);
    const watermarkedUpload = await uploadToSupabase(
      watermarkedImage,
      "previews"
    );

    return {
      original: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL}/storage/v1/object/public/${originalUpload.data.fullPath}`,
      watermarked: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL}/storage/v1/object/public/${watermarkedUpload.data.fullPath}`,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error processing image", imageURL, error);
    Sentry.captureException(error);
    throw error;
  }
}
async function applyWatermark(imageBuffer, logoBuffer) {
  // Applies watermark on the images.
  return await sharp(imageBuffer)
    .composite([
      {
        input: logoBuffer,
        tile: true,
        blend: "over",
        gravity: "northwest",
      },
    ])
    .jpeg({ quality: 75 })
    .toBuffer();
}

async function uploadToSupabase(imageBuffer, supabase, training_id, type) {
  const fileName = `${new Date()
    .toISOString()
    .slice(0, 7)}/${training_id}/${type}/${uuidv4()}.jpg`;
  return await supabase.storage
    .from("studios")
    .upload(fileName, imageBuffer, { upsert: true, contentType: "image/jpeg" });
}

async function updateUserPreviews(
  user_id,
  tune_id,
  previewImageArray,
  supabase
) {
  try {
    const { data: userData, error: perror } = await supabase
      .from("users")
      .select("preview")
      .eq("id", user_id)
      .single();

    if (perror) throw new Error(perror.message);

    const userPreview = userData?.preview || {};
    userPreview[tune_id] = [
      ...(userPreview[tune_id] || []),
      ...previewImageArray,
    ];

    const { error: updateError } = await supabase
      .from("users")
      .update({ preview: userPreview })
      .eq("id", user_id);

    if (updateError) throw new Error(updateError.message);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error updating user previews", error);
    Sentry.captureException(error);
    throw error;
  }
}

async function updateResultsColumn(user_id, tune_id, imageUrls, supabase) {
  try {
    const { data: userData, error: resultsError } = await supabase
      .from("users")
      .select("results")
      .eq("id", user_id)
      .single();

    if (resultsError) throw new Error(resultsError.message);

    const userResults = userData?.results || {};
    userResults[tune_id] = [...(userResults[tune_id] || []), ...imageUrls];

    const { error: updateError } = await supabase
      .from("users")
      .update({ results: userResults })
      .eq("id", user_id);

    if (updateError) throw new Error(updateError.message);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error updating results column", error);
    Sentry.captureException(error);
    throw error;
  }
}

async function fetchWithRetry(
  url,
  options = {},
  retries = RETRY_LIMIT,
  backoff = RETRY_BACKOFF
) {
  for (let i = 0; i < retries; i++) {
    try {
      const controller = new AbortController();
      const timeout = setTimeout(() => controller.abort(), REQUEST_TIMEOUT);
      const response = await fetch(url, {
        ...options,
        signal: controller.signal,
      });

      clearTimeout(timeout);

      if (response.ok) {
        return response;
      }
      throw new Error(`Fetch failed with status: ${response.status}`);
    } catch (error) {
      if (i === retries - 1 || error.name === "AbortError") {
        console.error("Fetch failed, no more retries", url, error);
        Sentry.captureException(error);
        throw error;
      }

      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, backoff * (i + 1)));
    }
  }
}

I am seeking feedback and a solution to ensure that all requests are processed correctly. My app is growing rapidly, and I want this solution to scale to handle at least a few thousand requests. A friend suggested migrating to AWS Lambda for better performance, but I believe there may be a bug in my code that I need to address first. Moving to Lambda without sufficient justification might lead to unnecessary complexity. Additionally, I'm wondering if the 60-second timeout limit for Vercel's free functions is insufficient for processing the images and saving them to Supabase. What are your thoughts?
Thanks!
When I run this on my localhost using ngRok it saves all the images but when it comes to the online production app, it saves only half of the images.
Also, give any idea how difficult it would be to migrate to AWS lambda or any similar services and what's the process.
